# How to know if Google form in Flutter webview was submitted successfully?

Tags: flutter, webview, google-forms

Let's suppose I have integrated google form into my flutter app and I want my users to fill it without fail and if they don't then I would want to restrict further functionalities of my app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a way to read the successful completion message of google forms in flutter webview.

We can create a method and use web view controller to read the JavascriptInterface of the page. The div where the successful submission message is always posted is called "vHW8K". So we can just check if this div has some value in it, if yes then it means that the form was successfully submitted

Future checkFormFilledStatus() async {
return await _webViewController.runJavascriptReturningResult("document.getElementsByClassName('vHW8K').length > 0") == "true";
}

[Completion message display div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLMXq.png)
[This is how successful completion is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ0l2.png)